# Cannot find hover effect on product box

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to replicate the image box on this page

http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/termekek/plc-hmi/unitronics/

on this page on my blog where the blog posts show i thought all i needed was thumbnail arrow buts its not showing correct with the css i have in the file

```
<style>

.thumbnail-arrow { width: 28px; height: 28px; position: absolute; bottom: -9px; right: 20px; background-image: url(./images/sprite1.png); background-size: 4300%; background-position: 7.993% 82.292%; transition: all 0s ease-in-out; }
</style>
```

```
 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
    } else { ?> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php     bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php  the_title(); ?>" /></a>
<?php } ?>
                     <div class="thumbnail-arrow"></div>
       </div>
```

I wish to replecate the hover effect here but I cannot for life of me see where the orange is being applied on the product image in the first link and the arrow

Answer (score 0):

That would be in your style.css on line 690.

```
/* Default Link Styles */
a { color: #333333; text-decoration: underline; line-height: inherit; }
a:hover, a:focus { color: #f87b06; text-decoration: none; }
a img { border: none; }
```

edit; and the arrow at line 1118.

```
.products a:hover .thumbnail-arrow {
    background-position: 5.442% 82.292%;
    transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: But how does that tell only the product image to have the hover effect ? how would i rename that to work on the blog page  i have tried having a tag around blog image but it doesnt change the hover?.

Comment: Add the classname of your blogpost to the hover. Looking at your blog that would be .products a img. example: .products a img:hover{color:orange;}